# Setting custom SNI Server name for Keycloak httpClient

Tags: java, spring, ssl, keycloak, sni

As we know Java has support for SNI since version 1.7. But there is a litter inconvenience, SSLContext is not able properly extract the server’s name from URL if it does not contain at least one dot. Thus, the ClientHello handshake message sent without server name and  proxy server responds consequently with default certificate instead appropriate cert.

It is my case, I am using self-signed certificates and local host names, for instance https://some-machine/auth. And I can live with that when it comes only for my code, I can implement my own `SocketFactory` which injects appropriate server name into `SSLSocket`, example:

```java
new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(context) {
    @Override
    protected void prepareSocket(final SSLSocket socket) throws IOException {
        List<SNIServerName> serverNames = socket.getSSLParameters().getServerNames();
        if (serverNames == null || serverNames.size() == 0) {
            log.warn("DefaultHostnameVerifier didn't detect host name. Host name [{}] will be injected", finalHostName);
            List<SNIServerName> sniHostNames = new ArrayList<>(1);
            sniHostNames.add(new SNIHostName("SOME-MACHINE"));
            SSLParameters sslParams = new SSLParameters();
            sslParams.setServerNames(sniHostNames);
            socket.setSSLParameters(sslParams);
        } else {
            log.info("SNIServerName is [{}]", serverNames);
        }
    }
};
```

**The real problem** happens when when it comes to third parties’ libraries like Keycloack. I am using via keycloak-spring-boot-starter. **It has its own `HttpClient` implementation**, and I couldn’t fined how I replace it or modify its properties? in order to inject the server name into it. Or may be somebody know another solution?

Comment: So, I still has no solution for that. Meanwhile I has deactivated SSL validation for Keycloak Adaptor by application.properties="keycloak.disable-trust-manager=true", I know it's not safe but at least it works ((